# Validate number from a string simplest way in Javascript (do not use regex)

Tags: javascript

i'm a beginner on Javascript. I have a problem. When i use `parseInt()` then use `isNaN()`, it worked well with params `a,b,c` but with 
`d` it couldn't run into `if` condition to log the message.

Here is my code:

```js
let a = "abc";
let b = "123";
let c = "abc123";
let d = "123abc"; //problem
let check = parseInt(d); //b,c,d
if (isNaN(check)) {
  console.log('This is a invalid number!');
}
```

What is the simplest way to fix this?

Comment: This is a common question that it has been answered countless times. Googled before.

Comment: yeah and "it didn't work" is not a javascript error

Comment: sorry. but if you read my code, you actually know that problem is console.log nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`if (!check || d !== check.toString()) {
    console.log('This is a invalid number!');
}`

Comment: or you can use `Number()` instead of `isNaN()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function Number(d)